# What is the relevant time for hats?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2014

I was wondering a bit after I got a Santa Lucia Hat from several different SE-pages. For getting the SL-Hat you have to vote on 15th of december, but for example I got the SL-Hat on meta, even if I created the account here on 16th of december (according to my time zone). So, what is the relevant time zone for hats? And even if the time zone is UTC, I am in UTC +1, so that should not be the answer...

Answer (score 1):

Yep, somehow I did not find the answer...
Solution is according to the comment from PeterJ, that hats are awarded +13h/-12h around the specific date in UTC, meaning that I can get more Lucia hats till today 13:00 UTC.